# apktool build apk fails

Tags: build, recompile

I am experiencing very annoying problems with the application apktool problem.
I do not understand what i am doing wrong, or what the problem is.
I tried this on debian , and on linux mint. I used different versions of apktool,

resulting in the same error:

```
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL3630495287059303807.tmp, -I, /home/awesomename/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /home/awesomename/out/./res, -M, /home/awesomename/out/./AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(Unknown Source)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Unknown Source)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Unknown Source)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Unknown Source)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Unknown Source)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Unknown Source)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL3630495287059303807.tmp, -I, /home/windows/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /home/windows/out/./res, -M, /home/windows/out/./AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.util.OS.exec(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 10 more
```

It seems it can not use aapt , but i read about apktool.
And it seems that aapt is build inside apktool , why is it not working ?

Comment: See also [apktool - How Fix brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = -1073741515) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441409/how-fix-brut-androlib-androlibexception-brut-common-brutexception-could-not-ex) for a different cause of the same error message.

Answer (score 59):

It seems there's some problem in building the resources while recompiling the apk.
what you can do is, when you decompile your apk use this command

```
apktool d -f -r apkfilename.apk
```

here -f is to replace previous decompiled apk's code and -r is to ignore the decompiling of resources.

this would prevent the resources from being decompiled and will simply copy the same resources when you recompile the apk.

Comment: Problem is, this would not let me see the values folders. Which is the only reason I'm decompiling the apk.

Answer (score 7):

In case you've been using v1 and now upgraded to v2, try manually deleting the framework file.

On windows 8 it's normally at `C:\Users\YourName\apktool\framework\1.apk`.

The file should be regenerated once you try to build something.

Comment: On OS X (macOS) it is at `/Users/<username>//Library/apktool/framework/1.apk`.

Comment: On GNU/Linux it's at `.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk`, although you can change it on any operating system with `--frame-path <dir>`. -- also instead of manually delete the file `apktool empty-framework-dir` should do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was solved by deleting the \framework\1.apk, making a backup on the files I modified, ereasing the dir and decompiling the *.apk again, etc...  (on linux, the path is **home/[user]/apktool/**...). After the update, apktool always loaded the old resource table. N

Answer (score 3):

For me, I solved this problem by first clearing apktool's framework directory by typing in the terminal.

```
$ apktool empty-framework-dir
```

Afterwards I uninstalled apktool and related files by typing

```
$ sudo apt purge apktool
```

Then i went to https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/ to get the latest jar file for apktool(apktool_2.5.0.jar as at the time of writing this).

On first run

```
$ java -jar apktool_2.5.0.jar b <MyAPP.apk> #Without ><
```

it works.

since I work with apktool most of the times I needed a situation where I can run apktool from anywhere so I gave the jar file execute permissions by typing

```
$ sudo chmod +x apktool_2.5.0.jar
```

Afterwards I moved it /usr/bin/ by typing

```
$ sudo apktool_2.5.0.jar /usr/bin/
```

Comment: thank you so much !!!! i was gone crazy with that aap2_64 error !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely seems like the aapt PATH problem I had awhile back. Have you added aapt to PATH? If you still have problems, I have made a good apk kit in bash to avoid all these dependency problems. It supports apktool, signapk, zipalign,adb, fastboot, and heimdall. Check it out. All you need is a current java install.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/toolkit-apk-munky-rench-t3026757/post58747626#post58747626

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t really enough information to give you a definite answer.

How ever you mentioned using different versions but the aapt issue was solved in version 2.4. Dependencies have been reduced to java version 1.8 or greater and the framework.

I use Debian and have the following:

- Apktool 2.4
- java version 11
- Android framework

That’s all it took to get rid of the aapt path error.

The last error I came across was unrelated to aapt but was on the framework so I ran this command

```
apktool empty-framework-dir
```

And it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the dir which include aapt file to your PATH. for example, export PATH=$PATH:./ ./apktool b

Answer (score 0):

try to install **ia32-libs** and update latest version of **apktool**. (if possible restart)

apktool requires "ia32-libs" which is not available after Ubuntu 12.04. install **ia32-libs**

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

Download latest version of **apktools.jar** - https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads

apktool complete installation guide - http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter same problem when run `apktool d foo.apk`(decompiled success) and then `apktool b foo`(recompile failed with similar error).

The `apktool` tool above was installed via `sudo apt-get install apktool` on Kali Linux.

So, the solution was visits `apktool`'s official site, e.g. https://connortumbleson.com/2017/01/23/apktool-v2-2-2-released/ (it's latest version at this time of writing), download it, md5sum it, e.g. `md5sum apktool_2.2.2.jar` to verify, then rename that apktool_2.2.2.jar to apktool.jar.

Then do `java -jar ./apktool.jar b foo` to recompile, it success without error (the generated apk located at ./foo/dist/foo.apk).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is apktool version you need 2.4.0

You must manually install it from ibotpeaches git hub

here some good info

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB6s10Uwpcs

and a automated script for kali 
https://github.com/catenatedgoose?tab=repositories

Answer (score 0):

In my mind the problem is how you install apktool...
I had the same problem and I did this and it worked very well:
For installation you first have to remove any installed apktool by the command:
`sudo apt purge apktool`
Then you'll have to install apktool but in a different way.
To continue save the link bellow as `apktool` in a directory.
[https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/master/scripts/linux/apktool]
Then open this link below and download the latest apktool.jar file: https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/
Then rename the file as `apktool.jar`
After that give both files the permission by the command:

```
Sudo chmod -x apktool.jar
```

And for the saved script:

```
Sudo chmod -x apktool
```

At the end copy both files in the directory:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

By the command:

```
Sudo cp apktool.jar /usr/local/bin
```

And the script file:

```
Sudo cp apktool /usr/local/bin
```

After that try running `apktool`in the terminal.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to include your apktool directory into your system PATH.