# Error when recompiling apk using apktool on mac

Tags: android, macos, apktool

I just moved from windows to mac las week and i tried to use apktool on it but when i try to recompile the file i keep receiving this errors

```html
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec: [aapt, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 9, --target-sdk-version, 21, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, --no-version-vectors, -F, /var/folders/rq/95s03v09065br4w8dyg6n__00000gn/T/APKTOOL13452202057815908857.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, arsc, -I, /Users/macbookpro/Library/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /Users/macbookpro/juusttest/res, -M, /Users/macbookpro/juusttest/AndroidManifest.xml]
 at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:477)
 at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:411)
 at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:310)
 at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:263)
 at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:227)
 at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:84)
```

Have anyone here faced the same problem ?
PS: java version "9.0.1"
apktool version : 2.2.2

Comment: I recommend to submit an issue at apktools github. https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/1131 Since it seems apktools issue.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317208/apktool-build-apk-fails; but it's also possible that you don't have the aapt executable. Try to execute `aapt` manually to see if it works.