# Can't recompile the apk file with apktool

Tags: linux, apktool, recompile, parrot

I decompiled an app with apktool_2.3.4 and i didn't make any changes to the app but when i run :

```
apktool b app.apk
```

I got the following error:

```
I: Using Apktool 2.3.4    
I: Checking whether sources has changed...    
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...    
I: Checking whether resources has changed...    
I: Building resources...    
W: /home/parrot/untitled/payapp/AndroidManifest.xml:1: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'compileSdkVersion' in package 'android'
W: /home/parrot/untitled/payapp/AndroidManifest.xml:1: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'compileSdkVersionCodename' in package 'android'
W: /home/parrot/untitled/payapp/AndroidManifest.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [/tmp/brut_util_Jar_6036700046333929352.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 15, --target-sdk-version, 28, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, --no-version-vectors, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL13088225914954905419.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, META-INF/android.arch.core_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_livedata-core.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_livedata.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_viewmodel.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.core_core.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.print_print.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable-animated.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, arsc, -I, /home/parrot/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /home/parrot/untitled/payapp/res, -M, /home/parrot/untitled/payapp/AndroidManifest.xml]
```

I am using Parrot OS the latest version

This also happens when I try to create a metasploit payload and bind it in an APK.

Comment: I thought APKTool was abandoned by its author back in 2012...

Comment: So what should i do ?!!

Comment: @jww That is not true, latest build (2.4.0) is one month old -> 2019-03-03 (https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/)

Comment: @Jerabek - APKTool was originally written by Brut.all. It was abandoned back in 2012 or so. I guess the new guy took the name for a fork. The new guy should provide a history and credit Brut.all.

Comment: Near duplicate of [recompile - apktool build apk fails - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317208/apktool-build-apk-fails)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and if you look at Apktool's github issues, you will realize [we are not alone](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20androidx). Apktool has obviously problem re-compiling resources with androidx, so if you are not changing resources, you can decompile APK with parameter -r (Do not decode resources) and then re-compilation is not a problem.

If you need to change resources, you will have to contact author to solve this issue.

Comment: The issue link is empty?

Comment: @user202729 Issues have been closed, check closed issues for details.