# How Fix brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = -1073741515)

Tags: apktool

When you reassemble the application again via Apktool, this error occurs. What is the solution?

```
 Log For : app.apk 

 Log Type : Recompiling 

 Log Recorded At : Sat 10-08-2019 12:07:17.06 


------------------------------------------------------ 
------------------------------------------------------ 

brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = -1073741515): [C:\Users\MC\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_6951838926850516236.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 15, --target-sdk-version, 28, --version-code, 452877, --version-name, 2.19.203, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\MC\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL396430661739840676.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, png, -0, wav, -0, m4a, -0, mp4, -0, arsc, -I, HELPER\Frameworks\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\MC\Desktop\apktool\MODDING\app.apk\res, -M, C:\Users\MC\Desktop\apktool\MODDING\app.apk\AndroidManifest.xml]

------------------------------------------------------ 
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This could be helpful 
https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/1870#issuecomment-423239077

Comment: Also try this before rebuilding `apktool empty-framework-dir`

Comment: @unloco That looks like the correct answer. Do you want to post it as a proper answer?

Comment: @user202729 it's been awhile, I forgot about this issue, if you'd like, you can post the answer with the adequate explanation, cheers

Comment: See also: [recompile - apktool build apk fails - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317208/apktool-build-apk-fails)

Answer (score 14):

Because `apktool` uses `aapt` internally to package the apk, if the content is incompatible with `aapt` then `apktool` will raise the error.

To fix the issue, tell `apktool` to use `aapt2` instead. Example:

```
apktool b --use-aapt2 -o out.apk directory
```

*Source: [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/1870#issuecomment-423239077)*

Comment: Note that this is not the only problem that can cause that particular error message. If it doesn't work then check the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317208/apktool-build-apk-fails) to try other solutions.